# Telegram Bot in pyhton doesn't save image on the desktop

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Hi i am making a bot that with the command /build "chatid" and photo attachment will save the chat id as a txt file and the photo simply on the desktop, i dont understand why it doesnt save the attached photo when i send it

```
import logging
import os
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext
from PIL import Image

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

def id_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    update.message.reply_text(f"Your Chat ID: {chat_id}")

def help_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    instructions = '''
    Instructions to build:
    1. First 
    2. Second 
    '''
    update.message.reply_text(instructions)

def build_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    try:
        # Extracting the integer value from the command
        if len(context.args) > 0:
            integer_value = int(context.args[0])
        else:
            raise ValueError

        # Saving the integer value to a text file
        file_path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop') + f"/{integer_value}.txt"
        with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
            file.write(str(integer_value))

        # Saving the attached image on the desktop
        photo_file = context.bot.get_file(update.message.photo[-1].file_id)
        image_path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop') + f"/{integer_value}.jpg"
        photo_file.download(image_path)

        update.message.reply_text(f"Integer value '{integer_value}' and image saved on Desktop!")
    except ValueError:
        update.message.reply_text("Please provide a valid integer value in the command.")

def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater("")
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("id", id_command))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("build", build_command, pass_args=True))
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.photo, build_command))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

i really don't understand why

Comment: Your code is written to be used with PTB <=v13.x. Please note that the PTB team no longer provides support for these versions and recommends to upgrade to v20.x.